# dbcc failing with Cannot continue the execution because... alwayson having a change of state event for each db

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, jobs, dbcc-checkdb

I got a job [DatabaseIntegrityCheck - USER_DATABASES](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html), failing with the following error:

> Date and time: 2018-10-29 02:34:13 Command: DBCC CHECKDB ([one of my
>   databases]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS, DATA_PURITY HResult
>   0x254, Level 21, State 1 Cannot continue the execution because the
>   session is in the kill state.

I get an alert email with the following error message:

> The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 193, which had been
>   reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 46. This error may
>   have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs
>   for failed operations immediately before this error message.

[image]

On the primary server I get this message:

> The availability group database "all databases" is changing roles from
>   "PRIMARY" to "RESOLVING" because the mirroring session or availability
>   group failed over due to role synchronization. This is an
>   informational message only. No user action is required.

[image]

and on the secondary:

> The availability group database "each database" is changing roles from
>   "SECONDARY" to "SECONDARY" because the mirroring session or
>   availability group failed over due to role synchronization. This is an
>   informational message only. No user action is required.

[image]

As I could not find out the cause of this error, I have escalated it to the sys admin friends, also because I suspect it is something to do with network.

question:
as nothing about this on the error log, where else can I find any information about this matter?

I have run [sp_blitz with markdown](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/10/getting-help-slow-server/)

```
EXEC sp_Blitz @OutputType = ‘markdown’, @CheckServerInfo = 1
```

and the results are [here](https://gist.github.com/jjradha/793b8a2acda241dbf91364e62931d309#file-the-result-of-sp_blitz)

I have also run the following command on one of my small databases `test1` which is part of the availability group:

`DBCC CHECKDB ([test1]) WITH  ALL_ERRORMSGS, DATA_PURITY`

and that gave me the results shown [here](https://gist.github.com/jjradha/06dfc2cec222e9657231ad8df7b62076) and important to say, on this occasion it did not cause any failover or change of state in the availability group.

**Update:**

Yesterday I changed the schedule of the job [DatabaseIntegrityCheck - USER_DATABASES](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html) from 2 am to 3 am and it upset the availability group at 3:43 am
It seems to be caused by the `dbcc checkdb`

[image]

Comment: Can you post the markdown output of sp_Blitz as described here: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/10/getting-help-slow-server/ I'm going to guess we're missing something about the server. Plus, can you try running a DBCC CHECKDB() manually on the smallest database you have? Ideally, use one that isn't user-facing, because you might actually be triggering AG failovers when this happens.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you resolve this?

Comment: @DanielFogazaRubiera I fixed the error yes, however, the whole problem was outside the sql server realm, and that's why I never posted an answer. I believe the answer by [Josh Darnell](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/259721/22336) can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced this behavior before, where the AGs "blip:"

- from PRIMARY to RESOLVING and back to PRIMARY
- from SECONDARY to SECONDARY

It's my understanding that, on a system with a small number of logical processors (1-4), and with multiple AGs (or AGs with many databases), some of these "blips" are unavoidable.  Especially if the server is a VM with even slightly noisy neighbors.

Availability Groups use a lot of worker threads baseline.  You can read about the thread requirements for AGs in detail here: [Thread Usage by Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/prereqs-restrictions-recommendations-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-ver15#ThreadUsage)

I'd suggest that you avoid having other CPU-heavy scheduled tasks run at the same time, in order to reduce the risk of these events occurring.  In this case, it looks like index maintenance was running at the same time as CHECKDB.  If you have a big enough window, try to spread these out so they don't overlap.